# assign value from array to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an array of 5 objects.

i want to assign object which is at index 1, to an NSSTRING.

```
nsstring *abc = [array objectAtindex:1];
```

i know this is wrong syntax, this is returning object , something like this.

how can i get value which is at index 1 and assign it to an string?

regards

Comment: What is the concrete question? Your code is ok and gets the 2nd item of the array.

Comment: @ Eiko ....is it?? but its giving <gfghf:767>, object not the value .

Comment: See the answers - the code is the same. Maybe it's a problem with the data itself, or the way you use it.

Comment: pheww..m going crazy on this..i hv an array with 5 objects..and when i am assinging it through these snippets its showing me <hghj:878>...crazzzzzy.

Answer (score 7):

Erm.. this is the correct syntax :)

Apart the name of the string class:

```
NSString *abc = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

mind that this won't create a copy of the string, if you need to copy it use

```
NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithString:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
```

As Eiko notes you can directly copy the string object if you need to:

```
NSString  *abc = [[array objectAtIndex:1] copy];
```

Comment: Why not just [[array objectAtIndex:1] copy] ?

Comment: That's true, because I thought it would confuse him, let me add it

Comment: Copied your answer? what are you talking about? you also answered 2 minutes later than me. This is called whine and man, please, avoid being childish.

Comment: hi ,thanks for response...i quick question...my array on console showing this    
    "<Coffee: 0x722f460>"
but when i tried ur snippet, i am getting crash log saying..."[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]"  what does dat even means? i hv objects in array, how can it be out of range??

Comment: because arrays are 0-based. This means that first element is at index 0, so use `objectAtIndex:0` instead that 1.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero based in Objective-C land. So...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];
NSString *abc = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Would return the second object in the array. Zero would return the first.

Comment: Why do you create an object in line 1 and throw it away in the 2nd?

Comment: @Jack: whatever other problems exist with this answer, a leak isn't one of them.

Comment: Well at least it has zero length and is autoreleased. It's a bug though and can easily break your code in a tight loop.

Comment: @Jack, We're not talking about a loop are we? First you copy my answer, then you vote me down, then you troll... nice.

Comment: @Jordan: let's assume `-init` instead that `+string` :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you man, neither I copied you (I answered BEFORE you). take it easy.. it's StackOverflow, not a rush for the ultimate win

Comment: @Jordan Even after the edit, you're still unnecessarily creating an NSString object that you don't use. `NSString *abc = [NSString string];` creates an empty string and assigns it to `abc` but then you throw the empty string away in the third line.